# Why does installing Rtools42 generate Windows setup error?

Tags: r, windows, rtools

When installing Rtools version 4.2 on Windows 10, I get a pop-up window with the following message at the end of the installation process:

*Unable to execute file:*

*C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe*

*CreateProcess failed;code 2.*

*The system cannot find the file specified.*

The only thing I have done previously is to install R (version 4.2.1.).

I fear ignoring this message will lead to issues later on.

Comment: Check out: https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery/fix-command-prompt-not-working.html

Comment: Fix 3 (Modifying PATh environment settings) solved the issue- thanks a lot!